# How do I detect a federated identity from federatedpassivesignin control if the user is logged in at the STS

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, wif, federated-identity

Hi I'm using the FederatedPassiveSignInControl on my asp.net site (called ChildSite) to get an user identity from a STS which is set up on another asp.net site (called ParentSite). The authentication of my site (ChildSite) is set to FormsAuthentication, so the FederatedPassiveSignInControl is located on ChildSite's forms authentication login page.

I have 2 scenarios. In the first the user logs in to ParentSite and continues to ChildSite via a link in ParentSite. In the second the user goes directly to ChildSite and logs in to ChildSite:

Scenario 1:

1. User opens *ParentSite* in browser
2. User logs in to ParentSite
3. ParentSite displays a link to ChildSite in browser
4. User clicks link to ChildSite
5. User goes to child site

Here the user comes to login page.
Wanted behavior is that the user is seamlessly redirected to the requested URL at ChildSite as he has already signed in at ParentSite.

Instead the login page is showed and the user has to click on the FedratedPassiveSigninControl button to retrieve his identity and then be redirected.
I cannot set the FedratedPassiveSigninControl property autosignin="true". It would always redirect the user to ParentSite when not logged in and that would break scenario 2.

I wonder how I detect, or how I get FederatedPassiveSignin Control (or other WIF components) to detect that the user is already logged in, not show FedratedPassiveSigninControl and just forward the user to his requested page.

Scenario 2:

1. User opens *ChildSite* in browser
2. User enters credentials in text inputs at ChildSite and clicks log in.
3. The requested page at ChildSite is displayed.

Am I missing something here?

Cheers, 
mortb

Comment: With FBA on the ChildSite, what credential store are you authenticating against? Is it the same credential store that ParentSite uses? If it is the same, why can't ChildSite just use WIF to invoke the normal STS login screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to add an additional querystring parameter to your 4th step in Scenario 1 so that when you finally get to your login page, you have an "if" : "if the querystring parameter is present then AutoSignIn = true".

This is known as "home realm discovery" although your scenario is not typical as hrd usually involves two or more stses and here you have to differentiate between the sts and forms authentication.

Comment: Where should I alter the autosign property? E.g: Should I check for the QueryString parameter (I'm thinking of using cookie instead :) and then set the autosignin = true if the parameter is present (and true)?

Comment: `Page_Load` is fine, all the federating stuff executes later.

Comment: I'd like to share a discovery I've made by somewhat *magical coincidence*:
By appending a querystring parameter named returnurl=<whatever> the first time you access ChildSite (when you are redirected from parentsite) you will automatically be sent to ParentSite for authentication instead of ChildSite even though Forms authentication is switched on in ChildSite. For this to work you must have passiveRedirectEnabled=true in you web config. We appended this parameter to our url to be able to redirect from ChildSite back to ParentSite (by clicking buttons etc) but it turned out to do auth as well!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a classic SSO scenario. ParentSite and ChildSite should probably be 2 different relying parties. If user goes to ParentSite, then whenever they hit a protected resource (anything that requires user to be authenticated), then they will be redirected to the STS for authentication. A session is established between the STS and the user browser and then and then the user returns to the ParentSite with a valid token (assuming a "happy path").

When they hit a protected resource on the ChildSite (e.g. through a link on ParentSite) they will be redirected again to the STS (e.g. they will be requesting a token specifically for ChildSite, a second Relying Party). This time, because there's already a session with the STS, the authentication step is completed already and a 2nd token is issued. All this works seamlessly for the user.

This chapter of the "Claims Guide" covers this scenario: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359102

An additional note: credentials should not be entered in any of the sites, but in the STS.

Comment: From what I've understood, ParentSite IS the STS. His problem is that the ParentSite IS the STS but the ChildSite can work both with Federated and Forms authentication. This is not a "classic" scenario since "classic" involves delegating the authentication rather than "sometimes delegating and sometimes not".

Comment: Yes, I sense that this is not a "by the book" architecture. If I had the time I'd rewrite authentication in ChildSite to become more general, but there is a lot of code involved in this...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with such architecture. I use it for some time, with the only difference that the loginpage has explicit FederatedPassiveSignIn controls - three to be specific. However, the remaining part is just like the one you describe - I login either with internal forms authentication or with one of the three external stses.